How to write universal code using composition API in Quasar?
Quasar website explains that to write universal code, the code that is in created and beforeCreate lifecycle hooks for Vue components is executed in Server Side Rendering (SSR). My question is: What about setup? How can I achieve SSR functionality with composition API? How can I write universal code in composition API? How do I determine which code is executed in SSR with composition API?

created and beforeCreate are lifecycle hooks. setup is the one where you gonna write your composition API stuff if not using <script setup>, not exactly related to a lifecycle. I mean, the whole question is about 2 different things. Maybe there is a relationship in your case but it's not obvious in the question.

How do I determine which code is executed in SSR with composition API? Is that clearer? @kissu

Gave a similar answer for Nuxt back at the time. TLDR is: mostly everything is isomorphic (both on the server and client-side). So parts are client-side only (like mounting to the DOM) and so might be server-only. Really depends on where you write your code. Assume it always is so that you have less troubleshooting and otherwise use some console.log so that you could see if you have the print of it in the terminal (server side) or in your browser console (client side). But Composition API has nothing to do here, same result in Options API.

setup = data+beforeCreate+created in terms of the lifecycle. Plus it can make use of suspense to make instance creation asynchronous. This is uniform in vue and isn't specific to quasar or ssr. If created is expected to run on server side, you can be sure its setup counterpart will run too

Thanks @kissu, and @Estus Flask for your comments.
To use Quasar in SSR mode:
quasar dev -m ssr

In a Vue component with composition API:
<script setup>
import { onBeforeMount } from "vue";

defineOptions({
  preFetch: () => console.log("I am in SSR!"),
});

console.log("I am in both!");

onBeforeMount(() => console.log("I am in SPA!"));
</script>

